# jQuery dropdown menu in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, menu, drop-down-menu

I saw this jQuery dropdown menu on the net and I love it a lot. It works perfectly in Firefox and all browsers except as usual Internet Explorer. In IE, it's freaking slow and annoying. How to solve this problem?

To keep things neat, please visit: http://sandbox.leigeber.com/dropdown-menu/index.html and you will see what I am talking about.

Comment: external links are still evil.

Comment: Seems to work OK in IE8 on my box... perhaps a bit more detail might help.

Comment: Works fine in IE on my 4ghz Core i7!

Comment: Make that a third, works fine in IE here too.

Comment: Try to give better titles to your questions.